# Transform a dataframe column using pattern

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to transform the last column in a dataframe:

```
2L  7800161 2L_7800161_SNP  G   A   999 PASS    REFCOUNT=198;ALTCOUNT=5
2L  7800182 2L_7800182_SNP  C   T   999 PASS    REFCOUNT=174;ALTCOUNT=21
2L  7800202 2L_7800202_SNP  C   G   999 PASS    REFCOUNT=152;ALTCOUNT=36
2L  7800231 2L_7800231_SNP  C   T   999 PASS    REFCOUNT=193;ALTCOUNT=8
2L  7800235 2L_7800235_SNP  A   G   999 PASS    REFCOUNT=199;ALTCOUNT=2
```

To something like this:

```
2L  7800161 2L_7800161_SNP  G   A   999 PASS    198 5
2L  7800182 2L_7800182_SNP  C   T   999 PASS    174 21
2L  7800202 2L_7800202_SNP  C   G   999 PASS    152 36
2L  7800231 2L_7800231_SNP  C   T   999 PASS    193 8
2L  7800235 2L_7800235_SNP  A   G   999 PASS    199 2
```

Could somebody help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `str_extract_all` to extract the numeric part from the last column, the output will be a `list`, we convert it to `numeric`, `rbind`, and create two 'new' columns.  If needed, we can assign the column that was modified to `NULL`.

```
library(stringr)
df1[paste0('new', 1:2)] <- do.call(rbind,
      lapply(str_extract_all(df1[,ncol(df1)], '\\d+'), as.numeric))
df1$v8 <- NULL
df1
#  v1      v2             v3 v4 v5  v6   v7 new1 new2
#1 2L 7800161 2L_7800161_SNP  G  A 999 PASS  198    5
#2 2L 7800182 2L_7800182_SNP  C  T 999 PASS  174   21
#3 2L 7800202 2L_7800202_SNP  C  G 999 PASS  152   36
#4 2L 7800231 2L_7800231_SNP  C  T 999 PASS  193    8
#5 2L 7800235 2L_7800235_SNP  A  G 999 PASS  199    2
```

---

Another option is `extract` from `library(tidyr)`. We select the column to transform, specify the new column names in `into`, use regex with capture groups i.e. characters inside parentheses to extract. We can also use `convert=TRUE` to change the class of the output columns to integer.

```
library(tidyr)
extract(df1, v8, into=c('new1', 'new2'), 
                 '\\D*(\\d+)\\D*(\\d+).*', convert=TRUE)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(v1 = c("2L", "2L", "2L", "2L", "2L"), 
v2 = c(7800161L, 
7800182L, 7800202L, 7800231L, 7800235L), v3 = c("2L_7800161_SNP", 
"2L_7800182_SNP", "2L_7800202_SNP", "2L_7800231_SNP", "2L_7800235_SNP"
 ), v4 = c("G", "C", "C", "C", "A"), v5 = c("A", "T", "G", "T", 
 "G"), v6 = c(999L, 999L, 999L, 999L, 999L), v7 = c("PASS", "PASS", 
 "PASS", "PASS", "PASS"), v8 = c("REFCOUNT=198;ALTCOUNT=5", 
 "REFCOUNT=174;ALTCOUNT=21", 
 "REFCOUNT=152;ALTCOUNT=36", "REFCOUNT=193;ALTCOUNT=8",
 "REFCOUNT=199;ALTCOUNT=2"
 )), .Names = c("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5", "v6", "v7", "v8"
 ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.6+
dt[, c("col1", "col2") := transpose(regmatches(V8, gregexpr("\\d+", V8)))]
```

You can convert the columns to `integer` if required by doing `lapply(transpose(..), as.integer)`.

---

```
dt = fread("2L  7800161 2L_7800161_SNP  G   A   999 PASS    REFCOUNT=198;ALTCOUNT=5
2L  7800182 2L_7800182_SNP  C   T   999 PASS    REFCOUNT=174;ALTCOUNT=21
2L  7800202 2L_7800202_SNP  C   G   999 PASS    REFCOUNT=152;ALTCOUNT=36
2L  7800231 2L_7800231_SNP  C   T   999 PASS    REFCOUNT=193;ALTCOUNT=8
2L  7800235 2L_7800235_SNP  A   G   999 PASS    REFCOUNT=199;ALTCOUNT=2
")
```